# avoid expanding list in android when no childitems

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I am trying to implement `expandable list` in `android`.

- In that list view when no child items available means it expand and lists some white spaces on my `view`.
- I need to handle it like only the childs are available the group has to `expand` or else it has to avoid `expanding parentview`.

Can anyone give suggesstions.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303314/expandablelistview-is-showing-indicator-for-groups-with-no-child

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sub Menu in App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20926524/sub-menu-in-app)

Answer (score 1):

By default getChildCount returns zero, and thus the ExpandedListView produces no children until it's overridden.

See that you haven't overidden this with a bad value, such as replacing the value there with another constant.  You should put a function here that returns the correct number of children given position as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

override the method `getChildView` properly. It will resolve the issue and also make `proper initialization` of child arrays for each group item.