# Search implementation in android ExpandableListView that displays only not empty resulting groups

Tags: android, mysql, expandablelistview

I am currently making app that is using `ExpandableListView` with cursors provided by `CursorTreeAdapter`. In my DB I have countries and cities of these countries.

Now I want to implement `SearchView` thanks to which I will be able to search a specific city. The tricky thing is that when I search I want to display only groups(countries) where relevant city is. I don't want to display empty groups.

For now I have `Loader` of countries in my main Activity and from there the resulting data is inserted inside my `CursorTreeAdapter` implementation inside which I am loading cities. Currently I only found only [this](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html) blog with search in `ExpandlableListView`, but there isn't implementing any mechanism hiding empty groups.

And that is how my tables look like

```
Countries table
|ID|Name

City table
|ID|countryID|Name
```

Does anyone has any idea how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is act at the base..

you might get from db return only those groups  with a associated cities, with a join clause:

```
select co.* 
from Countries co 
inner join City c on (co.ID = c.countryID)
```

but if you do not sound like a good idea..

another solution is check the row's visibility into the method `getGroupView` of the adapter `MyListAdapter` (I'm referring to the [blog](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/11/android-expandablelistview-search.html) of example)

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isLastChild, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
   ...
   view.setVisibility((continent.getCountryList().size() == 0) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE); 
   ...
   return view;
}
```

else...

read a similar post:

[ExpandableListView is showing indicator for groups with no child](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303314/expandablelistview-is-showing-indicator-for-groups-with-no-child)

in `bindGroupView` check if there are child elements and saves the information on the tag of the object view, 
then `newChildView` take on the tag, get the visibility and make the view visible or invisible (as I said before)

Comment: The first idea I don't think will work, because you are trying to work with two totaly different classes and I don't think that cild cursor can send some info to parent (group) cursor

Comment: read a similar post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11303314/expandablelistview-is-showing-indicator-for-groups-with-no-child